# How "filter" a input select with table data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a doubt with Cakephp 3 querys/filters.

I have a database with tables: Groups, Users, Posts and Relations.

**Groups contains** : id and name

**Users contains** : id, name and group_id

**Relations contains** : id, user_id, group_id

**Posts contains** : id, title, message, user_id, group_id

So, when a user gonna add a post, I need to make a "filter" which display in field " group_id " ONLY groups that is registered to him in relations.

-

Well, to explain I made a example:

Groups:
    id | name

```
1 - SEO
2 - P1
3 - P2
4 - P3
```

Users:
    id | name | group_id

```
1 - John - 1 (SEO)
2 - Mariah - 2 (P1)
3 - Peter - 3 (P2)
```

Relations:
    id | user_id  |  group_id

```
1 - 1 (John) - 2 (P1)
2 - 1 (John) - 3 (P2)
```

That is, table relations is saying: John can make posts for groups P1 and P2.

My problem is right here.

In " VIEW ADD POST", how I filter the results of input select 'groups' for display only groups is registered for the logged user.

And other, I need to make a Validator also, right?

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like that you are asking about passing the logged in user to the model layer, If I am right then you just need to read and use [Footprint](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint) plugin.

> **Footprint**: CakePHP plugin to allow passing currently logged in user to model layer

When this plugin is loaded and configured for `postsTable`, then you will simply modify the `posts` query with `beforeFind` event using the passed logged in user.